# How to force a MySQL query to return nothing

Tags: mysql

Is there a query that can be passed to MySQL from the shell that is guaranteed to return nothing (not `null`, not '0', but nothing at all)? I can construct a query based on my own database design that at this moment will return nothing, such as

```
select foo from bar where baz="not in my database";
```

but that is not guaranteed to work in the future if that value happens to get added, and will result in errors in other mysql instances if they don't have a table called `bar` or columns called `foo` or `baz`. I can select the empty string, such as

```
select '';
```

but that returns the empty string appended with a newline rather than nothing.

I can get close to what I want by just dumping the results, such as

```
mysql -e "select true" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

but going down this path made me wonder:
**Is there a query that can be passed to MySQL from the shell that is guaranteed to return nothing?**

Answer (score 1):

You can select from the [dual table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) like this:

```
mysql> select true from dual where false;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can also do this:

```
mysql> select true where false;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee MySQL to return nothing if you pass it the empty string:

```
mysql -e ""
```